ドットを含むホスト名を bind で設定可能ですか？
ホスト名に「.（ドット）」を含めた文字列の値を追加したいのですが、設定可能でしょうか。
例えば、ドメイン「example.co.jp」に「test1.test2.example.co.jp」というホスト名を追加したいと思っています。
インターネット上で検索してみたところ、半角英数字以外では「_（アンダーバー）」と「.（ドット）」は利用可能という情報は見つけたのですが、実際のURLとしてはあまり見たことが無く上記のようなホスト名を付与することに少し不安がある状態です。
合わせて、bindへの設定時は、ドットを含まない「www.example.co.jp」と同じような設定方法で良いのかという不安も持っております。
記述方法）
　test1.test2      IN A    NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN
　test1.test2      IN CNAME cname.example.co.jp

のような記述方法で良いのか？
あまりbindを触ったことが無く、現在稼働している環境に対して新しいホスト名を早急に決める必要があり調査不足な状態であることは重々承知の上で質問させていただきました。
ご教授の程、よろしくお願いいたします。

検索して出てくるこの辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ DNSレコードの登録ルール, Q. DNSに登録できるレコードに制限はありますか。, 【ドメイン】DNSレコード設定の入力可能文字は？, 【ドメイン】DNSレコード設定の各レコードの意味を教えてください。, DNSレコードの編集

BINDのゾーンファイル(Zone File)のフォーマットはRFC 1034(日本語訳)を拡張したものです。ゾーンファイルは複数のリソースレコード(Resource Recorde、RR)というもので、次のような形式です。
所有者(owner) TTL クラス(class) タイプ(type) データ(RDATA)

※TTLは省略可能です。省略した場合は、ゾーンファイルの$TTLで指定した値になります。
所有者とは実際にDNSとして検索されたときに探される名前のことです。DNSで名前を検索する場合、コマンドなどではホスト名だけであっても、実際に検索される名前はFQDNです。つまり所有者もFQDNで書かれることが本来のRRとして正しいのですが、あまりにも冗長であるため、ある程あ度省略した書き方ができるようになっています。記述された文字列によって、次の四つのパターンにわかれます。

無し(行が区切り文字であるスペースまたはタブで始まる場合)
前のRRと同じ所有者になります。
※所有者の所が省略されたかのように見えます。
@(アットマーク)
起点が実際の所有者になります。
.で終わる文字列
絶対名(absolute name)と言われます。
書いてある文字列がそのまま実際の所有者になります。
.で終わらない文字列
相対名(relative name)と言われます。
書いている文字列の後に.と起点を付けた文字列が実際の所有者になります。

起点(origin)とはゾーンファイルをマスターとして指定するときのドメイン名です。ゾーンファイル内でも$ORIGINで指定することができます。
なお、実際の所有者として名前やドメイン名等は一つ以上のラベルを.で区切った文字列である必要があります。絶対名や相対名も同じです。ラベルに使える文字は英数字、-、_になります。(_が含まれるラベルは、SRVレコードなどの特殊用途につかわれるもので、通常のホスト名やドメイン名などには使用できません。)

以上を踏まえて、質問のレコードにどうなるかを説明します。
起点(origin)がexample.co.jpであるとして、所有者はtest1.test2になっています。これは.で終わっていない文字列なので、相対名となり、実際の所有者はtest1.test2.example.co.jpとなり、これがDNSとして検索できる名前になります。このように相対名に.が含まれていても問題ありません。ただ、..のように二連続になったり、.から始まっている場合は、実際の所有者がFQDNとして正しくなくなるため、不正なレコードとみなされます。
